# how to remove cookies for cookieless domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have a subdomain called `cdn.domain.com`, from which I serve CSS, JS and some images.
When I run Google Chrome's `audit`, it says that I can imporve speed by serving those files from a cookieless domain.
I've searched on the internet and found mostly this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|xml|json|txt|pdf|mov|avi|otf|woff|ico|swf)$">
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
</FilesMatch>
```

But when I add this to my .htaccess in my root, I see no change in my requests, when I add this to the .htaccess of the `cdn.domain.com`, nothing happens as well.
When I look into the request headers I always see this:

```
Cookie:__utma=124771992.1672641002.1393489852.1393489852.1393489852.1; __utmz=124771992.1393489852.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); cve=7%2BOFANPFY6bPsm9274j8hJIz%2BPvLQRT%2FJZG9ftr2o7c%3D; cvp=dNuYumBN%2F642JaRgONUeEq1upp2y%2F%2FtDjt%2BBbV87W%2BA%3D
```

The subdomain is a subfolder of the global domain.
Both the global and the subdomain have this .htaccess:

```
# http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html
## ERRORDOCUMENTS
# http://askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html
ErrorDocument 400 /include/html/errorPages/400.html
ErrorDocument 403 /include/html/errorPages/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /include/html/errorPages/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /include/html/errorPages/500.html

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(copperviper.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>


<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|xml|json|txt|pdf|mov|avi|otf|woff|ico|swf)$">
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
</FilesMatch>

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 62.132.244.73

# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All", or any combination of:
#  Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cdn/

# REWRITE TO WWW
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6} [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# REWRITE TO SEF URL'S
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]

# COMPRESSION
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/x-php text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/octet-stream image/svg+xml application/font-woff image/svg+xml

# REMOVE BROWSER BUGS
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

# enable PHP error logging
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_value docref_root 3
php_value docref_ext 3

php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value max_execution_time 200000
php_value max_input_time 200000

# CACHED FOREVER
# MOD_REWRITE TO RENAME EVERY CHANGE
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A29030400
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified

# PROTECT .htaccess
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>

# Commonly used filename extensions to character sets.
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US

# Set the Time Zone of your Server
SetEnv TZ  Etc/GMT

# ServerAdmin:  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such as error documents.
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN bug@copper-viper.com

# SEND CUSTOM HEADERS
Header set P3P "policyref='http://www.askapache.com/w3c/p3p.xml'"
Header set X-Pingback "http://www.askapache.com/xmlrpc.php"
Header set Content-Language "en-US"
Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"

# ADD VALUES FROM HTTP HEADERS
SetEnvIfNoCase ^If-Modified-Since$ "(.+)" HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^If-None-Match$ "(.+)" HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Cache-Control$ "(.+)" HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Connection$ "(.+)" HTTP_CONNECTION=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Keep-Alive$ "(.+)" HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Cookie$ "(.+)" HTTP_MY_COOKIE=$1

# Optionally add a line containing the server version and virtual host
# name to server-generated pages (internal error documents, FTP directory
# listings, mod_status and mod_info output etc., but not CGI generated
# documents or custom error documents).
# Set to "EMail" to also include a mailto: link to the ServerAdmin.
# Set to one of:  On | Off | EMail
ServerSignature On

## LIMIT UPLOAD FILE SIZE TO PROTECT AGAINST DOS ATTACK
#bytes, 0-2147483647(2GB)
LimitRequestBody 10240000

## MOST SECURE WAY TO REQUIRE SSL
# http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-ssl-in-htaccess-examples.html
#SSLOptions +StrictRequire
#SSLRequireSSL
#SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "askapache.com"
#ErrorDocument 403 https://askapache.com

# Safe Request Methods
# Denies any request not using GET,PROPFIND,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,HEAD[403]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD|POST|PROPFIND|OPTIONS|PUT)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# Forbid Proxies ^
# Denies any POST Request using a Proxy Server. Can still access site, but not comment. http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/04/20/how-to-block-proxy-servers-via-htaccess/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}%{HTTP:FORWARDED}%{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}%{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}%{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}%{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR}%{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# HTTP PROTOCOL ^
# Denies any badly formed HTTP PROTOCOL in the request, 0.9, 1.0, and 1.1 only
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ .+\ HTTP/(0\.9|1\.0|1\.1) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# SPECIFY CHARACTERS ^
# Denies any request for a url containing characters other than "a-zA-Z0-9.+/-?=&" - REALLY helps but may break your site depending on your links.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ [a-zA-Z0-9\.\+_/\-\?\=\&]+\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# BAD Content Length ^
# Denies any POST request that doesnt have a Content-Length Header
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Length} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# BAD Content Type ^
# Denies any POST request with a content type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^(application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data.*(boundary.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# Missing HTTP_HOST ^
# Denies requests that dont contain a HTTP HOST Header.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# Bogus Graphics Exploit ^
# Denies obvious exploit using bogus graphics
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Disposition} \.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} image/.+ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# No UserAgent, Not POST ^
# Denies POST requests by blank user-agents. May prevent a small number of visitors from POSTING.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I haven't studied your code thoroughly but: 1) What Audit warns about is having larger HTTP requests—ignoring data received on the server is not going to fix that. 2) `cdn.domain.com` cannot prevent `domain.com` from setting cookies. You have to ensure that your app does not generate cookies for the complete domain.

Comment: How do I prevent my domain from settings cookies for those specific files?

Comment: How do you set cookies?

Comment: I only set cookies when a user is logged in using: setcookie($key, $value, $lifeTime, "/", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);

Comment: Fifth argument (`$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` in your case) is the domain. What does `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` contain?

Comment: It contains domain.com

Comment: @FIA2008 That's your problem then. The cookie will filter down to all subdomains. You need to set your cookies on a subdomain and then only that subdomain will have cookies associated with in. Typically you should set your cookies on 'www.yourdomain.com', then feed your static content from a different subdomain, eg. 'cdn.yourdomain.com'

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [manual page for `setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) explains about the `$domain` argument:

> Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' will make the cookie available
>   in the www subdomain and higher subdomains. **Cookies available to a
>   lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher
>   subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'.** Older browsers still
>   implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to
>   match all subdomains.

This implies that in modern browsers (I suppose that means almost all in practice) any cookie set for `domain.com` will be sent back by the browser to `cdn.domain.com` as well. That's how the cookie spec works and I don't think there's a clean solution.

Ideally, your cookieless domain should use an entirely different top level domain; or your site should be hosted in a subdomain, such as `www.domain.com`, so you can fine-tune cookies. I guess none are reasonable options for you at this point so you'll probably have to live with it.